# Congruences of ternary forms

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose $f(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ is an irreducible homogeneous polynomial, or a ternary form, of degree $d \geq 2$. Define
$$\displaystyle \rho_f(m) = \# \{(x,y,z) \in \{0, 1, \cdots, m-1\}^3 : f(x,y,z) \equiv 0 \pmod{m}\}.$$
It is easy to see that $\rho_f$ is multiplicative by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. I am interested in an estimate of the form
\begin{equation} \displaystyle \rho_f(p^k) \ll p^{3k-3} \end{equation}
for $k \geq 3$.

The analogous bound
$$\displaystyle \rho_f(p^k) \ll p^{2k-2}$$
is known for binary forms, see for example Filaseta's paper "Power-free values of binary forms".

The main obstruction from generalizing the argument for binary forms to ternary forms appears to be the following: in the binary form case, if $p | y$ say then we would have $\displaystyle f(x,0) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, and so $p$ must divide the coefficient $a_d$ of $x^d$ or it must divide $x$. In particular, when $f$ is an irreducible form, $a_d \ne 0$, so this gives a non-trivial estimate.

However, in the ternary form this is no longer the case. Even if we assume that $f(x,y,z)$ is irreducible, $f(x,y,0)$ may not have non-zero coefficient in $x^d, y^d$, and so we must settle for a much worse estimate in the case when both coefficients are zero, since the above dichotomy doesn't give any meaningful estimate.

This can be remedied if we apriori also insist that the coefficients of $x^d, y^d, z^d$ are all non-zero, but this seems an unnatural restriction and I am hoping not a necessary one.

Is there any easy way to show that $\rho_f(p^k) \ll p^{3k-3}$ for irreducible ternary forms $f$?

Thanks in advance for any comments or suggestions.